# Make a regex that matches certain binary numbers

Tags: binary, regular-expression

Your task is to create a regular expression that matches *most* binary numbers with an even number of `0`s and an odd number of `1`s (e.g. `"101100011"`).

The full criteria for the regex are:

- matches 90% or more of all binary numbers between `0` and `11111111` with even number of `0`s *and* an odd number of
  `1`s,
- doesn't match 90% or more of all binary numbers between `0` and `11111111` with odd number of `0`s *or* an even number of
  `1`s,
- works in most common programming languages.

Ideally, it should be short and creative.

The input string always has a length that is greater than 1, less than infinity, and only contains `1`s and `0`s.

I will upvote any answer that seriously attempts to match the above criteria. Once the activity around this question dies down, I'll accept the highest-voted answer that is at least only 1.333... times the length of the shortest answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20485486/1223693

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow _shhhhh_

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem, but there are none which can match. All binaries you assume as input are exactly 8 bits long (your examples indicate that leading zeros are provided) and thus odd+even cannot be true at all.

Comment: Moreover: short and creative doesn't sound very objective. If it is popularity-contest please tag it accordingly. (note: I don't think that this is a good example of a popularity-contest).

Comment: As @Howard points out, the 8-bit range specific criteria are impossible, but that would still appear to leave the initial statement of "**most** binary numbers with an even number of 0s and an odd number of 1s", later qualified with length "greater than 1, less than infinity."  I take *most* to mean >50%.

Comment: @Howard Thanks for noticing that. I feel stupid now.

Comment: I think there is a missing specification of "without leading zeroes" here, which would allow for 8-bit binary numbers <1111101 to match the target pattern.

Comment: Remaining thoughts...  Opening sentence suggests 9-bit numbers are in scope, while the "full criteria" section limits itself to 8-bits, but then later I read that *input strings* can be binary strings of infinite length. These are not *strictly* conflicting, but it's a bit of a head-scratcher. I would also suggest removing the word "most" in the opening sentence (since it suggests a portion of more than 50%) of even 0-count and odd 1-count (of any length, apparently at least 9 bits in the example string) but that is not emphasized again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following regex

```
(?=^1*(01*0)*1*$)^.(..)*$
```

works in many languages. It performs a perfect match for any binary of arbitrary length.

Basically, it consists of two parts which are joined via *and* by using a lookahead pattern:

- `^1*(01*0)*1*$` matches if an even number of zeros is provided.
- `^.(..)*$` tests for an odd number of digits in total.

The test run can be seen [here](http://ideone.com/k5CWtz).

Answer (score 0):

#### 80 characters long

```
^(?:(?(1)|(1))|0101|1010|(?:1{2})+|(?:0{2})+|0(?:1{2})+0|1(?:0{2})+1|)+(?(1)|a)$
```

Doesn't match some numbers that have an odd number over four `1`s in a row, e.g 01111101

Comment: so does this match **exactly** 90% of numbers between 0 and 0b11111111? (I tried to test, but apparently this regex doesn't work in Ruby.)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Whoops, edited question.

Comment: Ah, okay, well in that case, why the `{2}`s? Repeating the previous digit would be shorter.

Comment: And what's with the `a` at the end?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I don't quite know why I put those `{2}`s there... The `a` makes the regex fail if the the first capturing group doesn't capture anything, which should only happen if there is an even number of `1`s.

Comment: I've been able to get down to 52 characters with only the most basic regex features: `(1|0(00|11)*(10|01))((10|01)(00|11)*(10|01)|00|11)*`